# requests.get / urllib2.urlopen [Errno 8]

Tags: python, django, ssl, https, urllib2

I get the following error when calling:

```
requests.get('https://www.polymer-project.org')
```

or:

```
urlopen('https://www.polymer-project.org')
```

The error:

```
SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:507: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

This URL is working fine in curl and any browser.

Comment: you are using python 2 yes?  `pip install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1` or use python3, https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/749#issuecomment-19187417